# Java Swing support for animations

Tags: java, swing, html, animation, bitmap

Suppose you have to create a simple 2D animation, like the drawing of a graph where the nodes  can change their position. I was wondering how it would be different to create something like this using Java Swing or a bitmap based framework, where you can only draw points and lines

I mean: does Swing offer more than simply drawing on a canvas? If it does, **can you list the main instruments Swing offers to create animations that are not simple drawing primitives**?

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood what an accepted answer is, but, from my point of view, sometimes there is no answer that can be considered the accepted one, as there is no answer that is better than others or that "solves" a problem (that doesn't exist as the question is not like "how do I do this"). Talking about the two questions you cite, they are different, as this is, actually, a Swing question, a more specific question than the other where I asked for general pros and cons of swing and html5 technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [Java2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

There is also a [demo page](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/samples/suite/) available

Answer (score 1):

Swing is a GUI framework in which the Java 2D API can be used to create arbitrarily complex animations; the links from @stacker are exemplary. As concrete examples, I always liked the animation in this [particle simulation](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) and this [dynamical system](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/cliff/cliff.html).